# What would be the SQL query for my problem?

Tags: sql, android-room, android-architecture-components

I need help with a SQL query for room within an android app. There is a table questions. This table has 3 columns:

*id question id_sub_cateory*

Furthermore there is table_sub_categories with folloing columns:

*id sub_category id_category*

And table_categories:

*id category id_subject*

Additionally there is a table_subject:

*id subject id_questionnaire*

Last but not least table_questionnaire:

*id questionnaire*

Now I would like to have a SQL query to get following information:

*table_questionnaire.id table_questionnaire.questionnaire questionCount subjectCount*

So basically a list which lists all questionnaires with number of questions and subjects included. What would be the SQL query for that?

EDIT: So far I have used this query:

```
SELECT table_questionnaire.id AS 'id', table_questionnaire.questionnaire_name AS 'name', " +
            "COUNT(table_question.id_questionnaire) AS 'questionCount', COUNT(DISTINCT table_question.subject) AS 'subjectCount' " +
            "FROM table_questionnaire " +
            "LEFT JOIN table_question ON table_questionnaire.id = table_question.id_questionnaire GROUP BY table_questionnaire.id"
```

But this one is an old version because I saved each question with an ID of questionnaire, subject, category and sub_category. I recognized that this information is redundant. Now I save only the ID of sub_category. But now I have to change the query. I just don't know how!?

Comment: The table you want to create is for adding data or for just seeing information?. If its only for seeing the combined info of tables, use JOIN else got to create new table. (DB point of view).

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query which works:

```
SELECT
                table_categories.id,
                table_categories.id_subject,
                table_categories.category,
                table_sub_categories.id AS 'id_sub_category',
                table_sub_categories.id_category,
                table_sub_categories.subCategory,
                COUNT(id_category) AS 'questionsCount'
            FROM table_question
                LEFT JOIN table_sub_categories ON table_question.id_sub_category = table_sub_categories.id
                LEFT JOIN  table_categories ON table_categories.id = id_category 
            WHERE table_categories.id_subject = :subjectID 
            GROUP BY table_categories.id
```